# Как записать биты в файл?

Tags: c#, byte

Я знаю, что минимальная адресуемая единица - это 8 бит, т.е 1 байт.
Но мне надо записать по 9 бит 3 раза = 27 бит ( ну и придётся дописать еще 5 бит, чтобы было 4 байта ).
Как мне это реализовать на C#? Как мне записать по 9 бит?

Comment: я прокомментировал заголовок вопроса: «Как записать биты в файл?». ответ на такой вопрос: никак. формируйте байты (из битов в нужном вам виде) и записывайте их в файл.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Извините, но тогда появился еще один вопрос. Как мне сформировать байты из битов?

Comment: 1. переформулируйте, пожалуйста, вопрос (нажав [edit]). 2. специалисты по c# вам на него и ответят.

Comment: Так а в каком виде у вас эти биты сейчас? От этого зависит ответ, как из них сделать байты.

Comment: @CrazyElf Они у меня в виде значений типа int.